# Is there a way to disable Secure Boot startup message?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, secure-boot, elementaryos

So yesterday I disabled Secure Boot in order to run an undervolt software. I'm running Elementary OS on an Asus Q325UA laptop and when I reboot/cold start the system I get this message before the grub that says something like:

```
"booting in insecure mode"
```

for about 3-4 seconds. After this, the computer starts normally and there are no issues. It's not a huge deal, but I was wondering if there was a way to hide/remove this message since it's a little bit of an annoyance. Thanks again.

Comment: AFAIK there isn't. Oh, and the message is probably saying "insecure".

Comment: The only way that error message appears s grammatical correct is if it actually indicates insecure instead of secure.

Comment: You were right it said insecure, fixed